# Log all scp transfers with systemd-journald

Tags: systemd-journald

Does systemd-jurnald log incoming scp connections and what file they copied to what place? I would either like to access these logs or change the config so all of these file transfers are logged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sshd_config`'s man page has all the information you need, so try `man sshd_config` for a full description.

If you want to have all your ssh logs in a different file you will need to specify `SyslogFacility`, and `LogLevel` to specify how much information you want in your logs.

> SyslogFacility LOCAL7
>
> LogLevel INFO

Then you will need to modify your syslog's (whichever it may be) config file and add a line to specify where local7 (or the local number you choose) logs should be stored (this will be the path and file where you want the logs stored). In my case (`rsyslog`) I have the next line added to my `rsyslog.conf`:

> local7.*                        -/var/log/sshd.log

Remember to restart both services (syslog and sshd).

Answer (score 3):

scp, use ssh like transport (sftp too but in different way).
Depends of how is configured your system the journald left some logs in others files in my case (CentOS 7) ssh activity are available in /var/log/secure. 
But, you can not found file transfer info by default, just the ssh part, probably you have to increase the log level in /etc/ssh/sshd_config